# unable to load mongo extension for php

Tags: php, mongodb, debian

After trying for two days to get this to run;

```
sudo pecl install mongo
```

I finally got it done and added the extension to php.ini only to find out that it will not work for me.

This is what the install output was at the end;

```
Libraries have been installed in:
/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootVYRzXc/mongo-1.5.8/modules

running: make INSTALL_ROOT="/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootVYRzXc/install-mongo-1.5.8" install
Installing shared extensions:     /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootVYRzXc/install-mongo-1.5.8/usr/lib/php5/20090626/

Installing '/usr/lib/php5/20090626/mongo.so'
install ok: channel://pecl.php.net/mongo-1.5.8
# I edited etc/php54/php.ini here
sudo service apache2 restart
php --ri mongo
Extension 'mongo' not present.
```

But when I did `mongo --version` I get `MongoDB shell version: 1.4.4` which may be from my modulus installation. Could that cause mongo not to load?

When trying;

```
$mongoConn = new MongoClient("mongodb://<user>:<pass>@proximus.modulusmongo.net:27017");
```

I get;

```
Fatal error: Class 'MongoClient' not found
```

Comment: What error are you seeing from php?

Comment: I added the error to my post.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that mongo.so is found on in extension_dir:

```
php -i | grep extension_dir
```

Then cd to that folder and check for presence of mongo.so.

If present, make sure you have this in php.ini

```
extension=mongo.so
```

If this does not work: In certain virtual systems, such as those based on Docker, you may need to install your extension as the user associated with the "domain" or instance. A global (root user) installation may not work.

Comment: That gives `/usr/lib/php5/20090626` and mongo.so is there as well as the extension is in `/etc/php54/php.ini`

Comment: Verify you are using the correct php.ini by doing: php -i. Then find Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php.ini. Perhaps you think /etc/php54/php.ini is being used, but another php.ini is actually used at command line.

Comment: php -1 shows a whole bunch of code that's not in the one I edited, but no extensions. This is from phpinfo(); Configuration File (php.ini) Path  /etc/php54
Loaded Configuration File  /etc/php54/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files  /etc/php54/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed  /etc/php54/conf.d/imagick.ini
PHP API  20100412
PHP Extension  20100525

Comment: Try adding mongo.ini in /etc/php54/conf.d/. It's contents should be "extension=mongo.so". Then use php -i to verify the mongo.ini was loaded.

Comment: I did that, restarted apache and it still won't load. phpinfo() only shows one additional .ini file  Additional .ini files parsed  /etc/php54/conf.d/imagick.ini /etc/php54/conf.d# ls
imagick.ini  memcached.ini  mongo.ini

Comment: If I SFTP into /etc/php54/conf.d/ mongo.ini is not there and if I pull over the php.ini file extension=mongo.so isn't there either. If I do vi /etc/php54/php.ini then extension=mongo IS in there. I don't get it?????

Comment: Are you working in some sort of security restricted environment? Maybe a shared host or something? Perhaps there is some trickery going on with your drives? Another possibility - perhaps you are SFTP'ing to the wrong host!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68187/discussion-between-leoj-pyzynski-and-charlie-dalsass).